# inbox returning null while trying to access Lotus mail inbox using c#

Tags: c#, lotus-domino

I am using c# to integrate Lotus mail inbox woth my application.I am trying to debug my c# code and in that process i m getting a null value at my inbox near the code db.GetView("$Inbox").I am accessing Lotus mail client8 in my company and i tried accessing the same with my c# application. while debugging i even closed my mail client and tried but result remained same.Please help me where i went wrong..as its very urgent.Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

It's a hidden folder, use

```
GetView("($Inbox)")
```